# ¿Cómo se puede retornar valores de una función async?

Tags: python, funciones, async-await

Hola soy nuevo con las funciones async y quería saber si es posible retornar valores de una función async y si es posible como se haría.
El código es para un bot de música de discord. Quiero retornar el url para utilizarlo en otra función async

```
async def PLAY(ctx, *, search):
    query_string = parse.urlencode({"search_query": search})
   html_content = request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/results?" 
   + query_string)search_results = re.findall('watch\?v=(.{11})', html_content.read().decode('utf-8'))
url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0]

active_song = os.path.isfile("song.mp3")
try:
    if active_song:
        os.remove("song.mp3")
        print("Se ha removido la cancion")

except PermissionError:
    print("Hay una cancion reproduciendose")
    await ctx.send("Hay una cancion reproduciendose")
    return

await ctx.send("Se esta descargando la cancion")
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio("song.mp3"))
return voice
```

Comment: Sí se puede, como en cualquier otra función, con `return`. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de código en que esto te esté causando algún problema y explicar cuál es para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: El codigo seria el siguiente:

Comment: Al margen de la indentación incorrecta (que seguramente es un problema del copy-paste, para evitarlo encierra todo tu código entre dos líneas de ``` al pegarlo en stackoverflow), la función parece correcta. Observa que en el except tienes un `return` que no retorna nada, pero si no entra por la excepción llegará al `return voice`, por tanto ahí estás retornando algo. ¿No te funciona? ¿Qué problema tienes exactamente?

Answer (score 3):

Una función asincrona puede ejecutar un `return valor` como cualquier otra función.

Al ejecutar `return`, la función termina. La función que tiene un `await` sobre ella resume eventualmente la ejecución, recibiendo como resultado del `await` el valor retornado por la primera función.

#### Caso simple

```
import asyncio

async def simple(x):
    print("simple()")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    return x ** 2

async def main():
    print("main()")
    valor = await simple(5)
    print(f"simple(5)={valor}")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Tenemos una función `simple` que se limita a retornar su argumento al cuadrado tras una espera de 10 segundos, produciendo:

```
main()
simple()
simple(5)=25

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Caso múltiple

```
async def main():
    print("main()")
    task = asyncio.create_task(simple(5))
    while True:
        if task.done():
            valor = task.result()
            print(f"simple(5)={valor}")
            break
        print("trabajando")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Hemos redefinido la función `main()`, pues el primer código no tiene otra gracia que mostrar la sintaxis del retorno vía `await`. Un mejor ejemplo es hacer alguna otra cosa mientras `simple()` genera su respuesta.

Para esto, en lugar de hacer `await simple(5)`, creamos una *tarea* que se ejecutara en el futuro. Obtenemos una referencia a esa tarea, que nos servirá después para preguntar por ella:

```
task = asyncio.create_task(simple(5))
```

Nótese que tenemos que pasar una **invocación** a la función `simple(5)`, no el simple nombre de función `simple`. Piénsalo así: hay que poner los parámetros en alguna parte.

La ejecución del código continua de inmediato, sin esperar siquiera a que `simple(5)` empiece, entrando en un ciclo infinito.

En cada pasada preguntamos si la tarea ya terminó:

```
if task.done():
```

Si terminó (ejecutó un `return` o tuvo una excepción), podemos recuperar el valor retornado usando el método `.result()`

```
        valor = task.result()
```

Si `simple(5)` no ha terminado, la nueva función `main` ejecuta alguna otra tarea arbitraría, que aquí hemos modelado con un `sleep()`.

La ejecución produce:

```
main()
trabajando
simple()
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
trabajando
simple(5)=25

Process finished with exit code 0
```